# Prevent Selenium from opening new window

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, selenium-webdriver

today, I use Selenium to parse data from a website. Here is my code:

```
    public ActionResult ParseData()
    {
        IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(myURL);
        IList<IWebElement> nameList = driver.FindElements(By.XPath(myXPath));
        return View(nameList);
    }
```

The problem is, whenever it runs, it opens new window at `myURL` location, then get the data, and leave that window opening.

I don't want Selenium to open any new window here. Just run at the background and give me the parsed data. How can I achieve that? Please help me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Launching a Selenium driver within a web request is not a very good idea IMHO. Why don't you download that page at *myURL* using, for example, a **WebClient** object - and then, simply extract the required data from the response?

Answer (score 1):

Generally I agree with andrei: why use Selenium if you are not planning to interact with browser window?
Having said that, simplest thing to do to prevent Selenium from leaving the window open, is to close it before returning from the function:

```
driver.Quit();
```

Another option, if the page doesn't have to be loaded in Firefox, is to use [HtmlUnit Driver](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp#htmlunit-driver) instead (it has no UI)

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems that on each web request you are creating (though, not closing / *disposing*) a Selenium driver object. As I have said in the comment, there may be better solutions for your problem...

As you want to *fetch* a web page and *extract* some data from it, feel free to use:

- [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
- [WebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

A web application is not very a hospitable environment for a Selenium driver instance IMHO. Though, if you still want to play a bit with it, make the Selenium instance static and reuse it among requests. Still, if it will be used from *concurrent* requests (multiple threads running at the same time), a crush is very probable :) You have the option to protect the instance (locks, critical section etc.) but then you will have *zero scalability*.

**Short answer**: fetch the data by in another way, Selenium is just for *automatic exploration tests* as far as I know...

**But...**

If you really *have to explore that website* - the source of your data - with Selenium... Then fetch the data using Selenium in advance - speculatively, in **another process** (*a console application* that runs in background) and store it in some *files* or in a *database*. Then, from the web application, read the data and return it to your clients :)

If you do not have yet the data the client has asked for, respond with some error - "*please try again in 5 minutes*", and tell the console application (that's running in background) to fetch that data (there are various ways of communicating across process boundaries - the web app and the console app in our case, but you can use a simple file / db for queuing "*data requests*" - whatever)...

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So, I can't use Selenium in background like HtmlAgilityPack?

Comment: @Forte_201092 ... I guess not, *HtmlAgilityPack* looks like a  specialized **library** for dealing with HTML. On the other side, running selenium means starting **a new process** (the browser), "driving it" etc. Not a thing to do within a web request... Sorry if not helping...